# anaconda.cfg has no partition info

Tags: kickstart

Attempting to duplicate the install of RHEL 7 but the anaconda.cfg/kickstart.conf does not include the directory structure of the system being used to create it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.